# Insert data in a table from a file in PostgreSQL without double quote

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-8.4, greenplum

I have a file with some data which I need to insert in a table. I am using `gpfdist-external table - table` to load the file.

I am able to load data in table, but my problem is the fields in input file are enclosed with double quotes like "Emp Name" and the same is going to the database. I don't want these double quotes to go in database. Only the value inside those quotes should go.

I found this somewhere [ENCLOSED BY '"'] but it is not working in greenplum. 
Kindly tell me where i can change in my external table so that only Value inside the double quotes should go in database not the double quotes.

Thanks and Regards,
Sunny

Answer (score 1):

`ENCLOSED BY` is MySQL syntax. For PostgreSQL, use [COPY operator](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-copy.html):

```
COPY mytable FROM 'filename' CSV HEADER
```

If you want to specify quoting style, add `QUOTE 'quote'` - but `"` is already the default.

One more note: you should upgrade to PostgreSQL 9.2 (or at least 9.1).
PostgreSQL 8.4 is very old and not supported very well.

Comment: Thanks MVP, 
I tried this but i am facing the same issue in Copy also. 

My File is | delimited and in linux server.
Quote as '"' is for only csv delimited files. 

Here is what i have used 

COPY public.Data_test from '/sxm240/JunkYard/mdrtest.txt' with delimiter as '|' HEADER NULL as '';

And i m getting data in my table enclosed with double quotes like "NEW ORLEANS", whereas what i want is the value should be like NEW ORLEANS only.

Comment: Hi, I am sorry i didn't check properly. But my issue got resolved. Thanks a lot for your help. I have added CSV quote as '"'; as last and it worked...   Thank You, Sunny

Comment: Just i have 1 query.. whats the difference between COPY command and the [gpfdist-external table - table] to load the file? and which is better? Thanks again

Comment: I never heard of `gpfdist-external` command before - it must be something developed locally or by Greenplum